# Using Named Pipes as Files

Tags: windows, path, pipe, named-pipes, filepath

Simple question here (though perhaps not such a simple answer):

Is it possible to specify a path for an (existing) named pipe that can be used by programs as if they were opening on a normal file?

According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365783%28VS.85%29.aspx), name pipes on the local computer can be referrenced using the following path syntax: `\\.\pipe\PipeName`, yet I'm having no luck using this from standard Windows programs.

As a side point, if anyone has any suggestions for interfacing with programs that are only capable of using the file-system in a more efficient manner than physical I/O (e.g. named pipes), I would be glad to take them.

Comment: Note that I've asked question on StackOverflow because it's ultimately related to a programming project of mine. If it helps, I'm using C#, though I suspect it won't matter for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would only work if the programs are using the Win32 API CreateFile() function to open the files.